# Using ngclass in Stencil.js

Tags: angular, stenciljs

The below is the code in Angular 2. Could someone explain how to use ngclass in Stencil.js.

I have created the component is Angular2. Now trying to recreate the same in Stenciljs:

```
<div class="inner_holder" [ngClass]="isSelected(day)">
  <div class="col day">{{day.month}}</div>
     <div class="col date">
       <span>{{day.date}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
isSelected(day) {
  return (day.fullDay === this.selectedDay) ? "active" : "";
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use following syntax:

```
<div 
  class={{
    'error': this.hasError,
    'hidden': !this.isOpen
  }}
>
```

Comment: You can not only have conditionals but even dynamic class names: `const miracle= '123'` and in your HTML element `... class={{'foo': true, 'hidden': !this.isOpen, [\`bar--${miracle}\`]: true}}` will result in `class="foo hidden bar-123"` when condition resolves to true.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using ngClass, I would use either className or class variable and add some jsx syntax to it. For example, if you want to style a button based on its activity you would do

```
 <button onClick={() => this.doSomething()}
  class={ 'vote' +  (this.isActive === -1 ? ' active' : ' inactive') }>
```

Which would give it the class "active" when the variable isActive returns true.